# disable-output-escaping="yes", any reason why it should not work on the body of an announcement?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

Content query web part on a series of announcement lists.

disable-output-escaping="yes" does not work on the 'body' field

Any clue on why?

I have tried both on SP online and SP 2010 enterprise.
I have added body to the CQWP modified and listed it as RichHTML

Comment: Check to make sure your custom template is being called. Can you post the code?

Comment: I have realized it is working if I set the template called 'NoImage' which strangely (and stupidly) it is called Title and Description in the dropdown. If I take that one and leave the field called 'description' and I type into it, body, then the disable-output-escaping works. If I change it to have body as the name of the field, it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: does it look like the following? <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Body" />

Comment: Yes, that was my original, with @Description it works. I have already wrote the definition of 'Body' since in the same itemstyle file there is a modified template for a blog post (where body is still the body of the message)

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemStyle.xsl, create a new template and add this code. Make sure you publish it and select the template in the web part properties.

```
 <xsl:template name="Announcement" match="Row[@Style='Announcement']" mode="itemstyle">
      <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
          <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
              <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
          <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
              <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <div class="item link-item">
          <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
          <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
              <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
              <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
          </a>
          <div class="description">
              <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Body" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
```